# Make a field required/not required based on condition in serenity-platform

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

I am working on a serenity platform project. Any idea how can I make the field required/not required based on a condition inside AbcDialog.ts file. Thanks

Comment: Check sample northwind project for this. Also you can check editors for how it's works.

Answer (score 1):

Serenity.EditorUtils.setRequired(this.form.SomeField, yourCondition);

Answer (score 0):

In the `updateInterface()` in your dialog.ts you can write TypeScript code to show/hide conditionally some fields like this:

```
protected updateInterface() {
  super.updateInterface();

  if (this.entity.Status === Enums.RomTicketingStatus.Validated) {
    if (dateOperatingStartDate > dateMin) {
      this.toolbar.findButton('undo-delete-button').show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi KilroyFR, that's correct - but is not an answer to to question of making a field "required" ;-). Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `[Required]` attribute on your form field for implementation.
2. In the `AbcDialog.ts` file, override the function `onDialogOpen()` and put your logic of required/not required in it.